# Why doesn't wordpress create an unique index for `wp_users`.`user_login`?

Tags: wordpress, database-design

In this page, you can see what I mean,

http://codex.wordpress.org/Database_Description#Table:_wp_users

It only creates a normal index for the `user_login` column while I think an unique index should be created for it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well since the unique index (primary key) is the ID column, the coder probably didn't see the need to define another column in the table as unique. As you point out, though, user_login column is indexed so that gives the performance advantages when querying that table.

Comment: so we don't need to worry about duplication here? i think because what the chance of two registration request with the same login occur in the same time...

Answer (score 0):

Don't know wp, but maybe it needs to allow for multiple `user_logins` with different `user_status`?